# Reading In .csv File With Different Data Types

Tags: c++, csv

I have to read in a .csv file with data which has a newline character at the end of each object's data.  Below is an example of the file:

```
5201,Egestas LLC,Clear,NA,NA,408881,544329
5202,Elementum Sem Associates,Clear,NA,NA,426281,528325
```

I have been trying to use various `getline(inFS, number, ',')` statements, however, have been getting `invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char**' [-fpermission]`.  Is this because `getline()` can only take in strings?  Is there an easier or more specific way to read in .csv files?

Comment: `std::getline(inFS, number, ',')` wouldn't cause that error. Can you show a minimal example of the real code that causes this problem?

Comment: See Dietmar's excellent code here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18818861/2704585 to get you started.